# How to show console.log in mobile simulator for angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging, ionic2, console.log

I want to debug javascript inside mobile phones.

So please provide some piece of code or library how to show `console.log` in android/iphone simulator. It's better to show it in phone screen.

I am using `angular2` `ionic2`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you a remote tool like [jsconsole](https://jsconsole.com/)

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('ngConsole', []).controller('consoleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.messages = [];
    $scope.log = function(msg) {
      $scope.messages.push({
        type: 'log',
        text: msg,
        date: new Date()
      });
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="ngConsole">
  <div ng-controller="consoleController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="msg in messages">
        [{{$index + 1}}] {{msg.type}} {{msg.text}} {{msg.date}}
      </li>
      <li ng-if="messages.length === 0">
        <i>no results messages...</i>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="log('ok')">click</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```